# how to get hostname and port from odbc

Tags: db2, odbc

[image: ODBC Driver]
Hi, I have configured the System DSN and it is working well. So I forgot about the **hostname address and port number**, how can find it through it? When I select the data source and click configure, it only tells me the user id and dbalias. I also looked into the registration table, only find something like this

> " Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\BUS]
>   "Driver"="C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLIO.DLL"

"""

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DB2 database connections are configured by the DB2 client software on your machine.  When the connections have been defined within the client software they are then exposed to the ODBC Data Sources panel.  You can't configure them via the control panel.

To view them, open a DB2 Command Window, and issue the command `db2 list db directory`.  This will list all databases your system knows about:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2 list db directory

 System Database Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 2

Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = SAMPLE
 Database name                        = SAMPLE
 Node name                            = DB2AED1
 Database release level               = 10.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Remote
 Catalog database partition number    = -1
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =

Database 2 entry:

 Database alias                       = IBMDSMR
 Database name                        = IBMDSMR
 Local database directory             = C:
 Database release level               = 10.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

In the above example, the "Directory Entry Type" indicates whether the database is local ("Indirect"), i.e., you have the DB2 server running on your machine) or if the database is remote ("Remote"), like the `SAMPLE` database above.

To see the connection details for `SAMPLE`, make note of the **Node name** (`DB2AED1` in the example above) and issue the `db2 list node directory` command:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2 list node directory

 Node Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 1

Node 1 entry:

 Node name                      = DB2AED1
 Comment                        =
 Directory entry type           = LOCAL
 Protocol                       = TCPIP
 Hostname                       = mydb2.stackoverflow.com
 Service name                   = 50000
```

You can see that `DB2AED1` is on the host `mydb2.stackoverflow.com` and on port `50000`.  If, for some reason, the "Service Name" field has a name, then you'll need to look that up in the services file (`%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\services` on Windows, or `/etc/services` on Linux)